# TabIndex seems not working on vs2010 expression for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a few contorls and I set the tabindex for the control that I want to stop. I use the emulator to test it. After typing the enter button on the key pad, the cursor stay on the textbox. Would someone show me the link or code to make it work? Thanks in advance.

The following is my code for the controls:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtUser" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="1" Style="{StaticResource txtStyle_24}" FontSize="32"   />
 <TextBlock x:Name="Password" Text="Password :" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"    Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle_24}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="32" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
  <PasswordBox x:Name="psd" PasswordChar="*" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"   IsTabStop="True" 
                  TabIndex="2"  Style="{StaticResource PasswordBoxStyle_24}" FontSize="32"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TabIndex` doesn't make sense in `Windows Phone`

If you want to move focus to next `TextBox`, subscribe to `KeyUp` event and check `e.Key == Keys.Enter`. Than move focus with `textBox.Focus()`

I saw behavior for this but can't find a link now